# python launch/wait on "paired" processes in parallel (probably popen/wait/subprocess?)

Tags: python, subprocess, wait

I'm reasonably sure some functionality already exists to do this, but I haven't been able to find it.  What I'm basically trying to do is what we'd write in BASH as:

```
( sleep 1; echo "one" ) &
( sleep 2; echo "two" ) &
( sleep 3; echo "three" ) &
( sleep 4; echo "four" ) &
```

and have the entire thing execute in four seconds (not ten seconds)...

More generally, consider the case where I have a long list of processes that I need to run: (A1, B1, C1, D1 ...).  I also have a list of "paired" processes, let's call them (A2, B2, C2, D2...)  When any 'x1' processes finishes, I want to launch the corresponding 'x2' process, but I want to have all the x1 processes start in parallel, and as each one finishes I want the x2 process to be launched.

I've figured out how to use subprocess.Popen, push each instance into a list, and then wait on all of those to finish, but I've only been able to wait on the entire initial set, and THEN fire off the second set.  This is better, but not ideal by any stretch.  This seems like something that shouldn't be too terribly hard, but I haven't been able to find it.

Another way to think about this is that if I have ten paired processes, immediately after invocation I'll have ten running processes, and ten OTHER processes each waiting on one of the first ten to finish.

(This actually needs to solve a larger, more general problem but once I can solve this case I can generalize and scale it...)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in Python in many different ways.  Here are three obvious ones:

- The same way the shell solves it.  This is probably the easiest, at least on a Unix-like system, but it enforces some separation you may not want and does not work on Windows.
- Through polling.  If you have nothing to do while polling, this may be a waste of system resources.
- Through threading.  This is the lightest weight, but also the trickiest to get right.

The way the shell handles this is that:

```
( sleep 1; echo "one" ) &
```

forks off a sub-shell.  The sub-shell forks off a sub-sub-shell, and the sub-sub-shell `exec`s the `sleep 1`.  The first sub-shell now waits for the second sub-shell, and when that finishes, execs (no fork required this time) `echo "one"`.  (Meanwhile the main shell does not wait at all.)

Note that the number of processes here was 3: the main shell, the sub-shell, the sub-sub-shell which became the first echo, and then the first sub-shell became the second echo.  The main shell can wait for, and hence get the result-status of, the first sub-shell, but it cannot see the sub-sub-shell at all.

To do this directly in Python, either call a shell to run your two commands in sequence—this shell will fork once for the first command, then run the second directly—or use `os.fork()`.  If you're the child of the fork, use `subprocess` (with `.call` or `.Popen` or whatever) to run the first command, then use `os.exec` to runs the second command.  Alternatively, you can add yet more processes, and/or use `multiprocessing` (which adds a fancy communications mechanism between your various Python processes, so that you can do a lot more useful things, but it's even heavier-weight).

To use polling, note that a `subprocess.Popen` instance has a `poll` method.  Call this to tell whether the process is still running, or has finished.

To use threading, spin up threads that invoke `subprocess.Popen` and/or that invoke the `.wait` method on the created subprocess and then spin up the next one in the chain.  You'll need to add your own locking around any variables shared across the various threads (such as the various work-lists—it may make sense to divide them up before spinning up the threads, so that each thread has a private work-list and merely contributes the final results, if any, under a lock).

Comment: so I sort of follow what you're saying here, but to be honest some of this went whizzing by.  The shell method explanation made sense, but if my more general case is more like "I need to be able to run multilpe groups of *several* commands serially, does that change how we'd approach this?  In my head I keep thinking this should be something like "push a list of sequential A1,A2,A3... commands to be run into a list, then push another set of sequential B1 B2 B3 commands onto a different list (and so on) and then start working on each list of commands in parallel....

Comment: Let's try another example, shell-style: If you know in advance that you want to have Worker X run commands X1, then X2, then X3: create worker X, have X run X1 and wait for it. Then have X run X2 and wait for it. Then have X run X3, perhaps via exec. When this *won't* work: Suppose you know that you want X to run some things, but until X has started X1, and Y has started and finished Y1 and Y2, you aren't sure if X should run X2a or X2b. That depends on the results of Y1 and Y2. If X is independent of Y, how will X know what Y saw?